# Como mostrar los datos de un usuario logueado

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas, algunas forma de mostrar los datos de un usuario logueado?

Necesito que despues que un usuario se loguea, en otra pagina me muestre los datos de este usuario:

Tengo dos tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi código con el cual estoy validando e intentando extraer los datos del usuario.

```
<?php 
require_once('conexion.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $usuario=$_POST["nusuario"];
    $contrasena=$_POST["ncontrasena"];
    $usuario = stripslashes($usuario);
    $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($usuario);
    $contrasena = stripslashes($contrasena);
    $contrasena = mysql_real_escape_string($contrasena);
    $id_emp="";

    $sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND (contrasena='$contrasena' AND estado='Activo') ";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id_emp=$row["id_empleado"];

          }
            $_SESSION['iduser']=$usuario;

          $sql2="SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE id_empleado='$id_emp'";
          $result2=$conn->query($sql2);
          if ($result2->num_rows == 1) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION["nombre"]=$row["nombre"];
                $_SESSION["apellidos"]=$row["apellidos"];
                $_SESSION["tipo"]=$row["tipo"];
                $_SESSION["dni"]=$row["dni"];
                $_SESSION["ubicacion"]=$row["ubicacion"];
                $_SESSION["telfmovil"]=$row["telfmovil"];
                $_SESSION["email"]=$row["imagen"];

            }


            // header("Location: ../venta_venta.php");
          }


        // if($row = mysql_fetch_array($execute)){
        // }


            // $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


            $mensaje = "¡Bienvenido al Sistema!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$mensaje');</script>";
            header( "refresh:0.2;url=../venta_venta.php" );
    }else{

        $mensaje = "Error! La contraseña o usuario ingresado son incorrectos";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$mensaje');</script>";
        header( "refresh:0.2;url=../login_agro.php" );

    }

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Como ven en el codigo, extraigo los datos de mi tabla empleado y lo almaceno en esas variables $_SESSION[]. Pero ahora quiero mostrar esos valores almacenados en otra pagina llamada **mantenimiento_cuenta:**

```
<?php 
require_once('verifica.php');

?>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="idnombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" REQUIRED disabled class="form-control" id="idnombre" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nombre']; ?>">
      </div>
```

Y el error que me manda es el siguiente:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: nombre in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PROYECTO_WEB\mantenimiento_cuenta.php</b> on line <b>178</b><br />
```

Y no entiendo porque. Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si, y aun me genera tal error. :/

Comment: Te refieres a esto?:
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result2=$conn->query($sql2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia estas filas:

```
$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($usuario);
$contrasena = mysql_real_escape_string($contrasena);
```

a

```
$usuario = $conn->real_escape_string($usuario);
$contrasena = $conn->real_escape_string($contrasena);
```

Estas mezclando `mysql`con `mysqli`

Otro fallo esta en esta linea:

```
....
if ($result2->num_rows == 1) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
....
```

deberías hacer el fetch sobre `$result2`:

```
....
if ($result2->num_rows == 1) {
            while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                              ^^^-- Aquí
....
```

Comment: No me había fijado, pero aun así se mantiene el error. :/

Comment: soy algo nuevo en este lenguaje, pero me salio esto: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Mi error. En efecto el error estaba en $result2, ya que extraía valores de otra tabla... Me has salvado.