# Cómo obtener nombre del usuario logueado

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de obtener el nombre del usuario logueado, lo tengo almacenado en una tabla MySQL de la siguiente forma:

[image: Tabla Usuarios]

Aquí mis archivos PHP:

login.php

```
<?php
// Include config file
require ('connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['contrasena'])){
    //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    //3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
    if ($count == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    }else{
        //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
        $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    header('Location: menu-ppal.php');
}else{
    //3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Iniciar Sesion
        </title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
                <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <?php echo $fmsg; ?> 
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">
                    Please Login
                </h2>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nombre de Usuario</span>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
                </div>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Acceder</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Conexion fallida" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'ops-navieramar');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Seleccion de base de datos fallida" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

verificar-usuario.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

} else {
    //no existe, debes redireccionar
    header("Location: login.php");
}
$user=$_SESSION['usuario'];
?>
```

Y tengo otro archivo donde quiero mostrar el nombre del usuario logueado, en realidad no es solo para mostrarlo allí, sino también para usarlo en otras partes del código, solo que no sé cómo traer ese dato.

menu-ppal.php

```
<?php
require ('connection.php');
require ('libreria/verificar-usuario.php');

echo $user;
?>

<html dir="ltr" lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Menú Principal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a><br>
    <div>
      <table border="0" align="center" style="width: 70%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 33%; background-color: white;"><img style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-buques" src="img/Icono%20Buques.png"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 33%; margin-left: 36px; background-color: white;"><img style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-nominaciones" src="img/Icono%20Nominaciones.png"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white; height: 170.95px;"><span style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><img style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-documentos" src="img/Icono%20Documentos.png"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>

      </p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

En menu-ppal.php logro mostrar el usuario, a modo de prueba, mas no encuentro forma de mostrar el nombre real del usuario.

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí: el código que compartes presenta vulnerabilidades muy graves de seguridad y no debería ser usado de cara a usuarios ni en entornos de producción. Tiene problemas de inyección SQL, XSS, fijación de sesión, contraseñas en texto plano... y eso sólo el fichero login.php. Desde el punto de vista de la seguridad, es bastante preocupante.

Comment: A perder de lo indicado por @AlvaroMontoro también se aprecia un problema de codicifaciones de caracteres. Aparte de ser una mala práctica guardar las contraseñas en texto plano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolver el problema basandome en esta otra pregunta y sus respuestas:

[Como mostrar los datos de un usuario logueado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15062/como-mostrar-los-datos-de-un-usuario-logueado)

De igual manera, muchas gracias a los otros usuarios por su colaboración.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el **nombre completo** del usuario y no su usuario puedes usar `mysqli_fetch_row` que devuelve las filas o la fila según la consulta.

Con `mysqli_num_rows($result)` sólo obtienes si existe alguna fila de registro.

Podrías añadir lo siguiente a tu código justo cuando compruebas que existe el usuario.

```
if ($count == 1) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        $fila = $result->fetch_row();

        /* la columna cuatro corresponde con la columna del nombre completo */
        $nombreusuario = $fila[4];

        /* Podrías guardarlo como variable de sesión */
        $_SESSION['nombreusuario'] = $nombreusuario;

        /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
        $resultado->close();

    } else {

        //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an 
        error message.

        $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";

    }

}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
```

Tienes más información [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Por otra parte incidir en el comentario que te ha dejado @Alvaro, tu código es vulnerable, puedes echarle un vistazo a esta otra entrada para saber más de la [inyección sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Comment: Aun agregando el código que me indicas, al tratar de hacer `echo $_SESSION['nombreusuario'];`, me devuelve el siguiente error: Notice: Undefined index: nombreusuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\agente-nav-online\menu-ppal.php on line 6, al parecer no se está guardando nada en la variable de sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una variable llamada `$fila` justo debajo de $count de esta forma:

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Esa variable almacenara los campos de tu BD pudiendo mostrar el nombre del usuario logeado de esta forma:

`echo $fila["usuario"];`

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

En tu **login.php** intentas almacenar en una variable de sesión el nombre de usuario:

```
if ($count == 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
}
```

Para que esto funcione la orden `session_start();` deberá estar al comienzo de tu código, ya que de otra forma no funcionará. Una vez almacenes la sesión correctamente podrás mostrarla en cualquier otra página utilizando dicha variable de sesión:

```
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['usuario'];
```